# Bootstrap like training to LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a dataset of size 273985 x 5 that I'm training as a path prediction problem. I chose an LSTM inspired by this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9225479

I have a baseline implementation as such:

```
# lstm autoencoder recreate sequence
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.utils import plot_model

# define input sequence
my_sequence = np.array(sample)

# reshape input into [samples, timesteps, features]
n_in = len(my_sequence)
my_sequence = my_sequence.reshape((1, n_in, 5))

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(n_in,5)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_in))
model.add(LSTM(10, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# fit model
model.fit(my_sequence, my_sequence, epochs=300, verbose=0)

# structure of the model and the layers 
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file=path)

# demonstrate recreation
predicted = model.predict(my_sequence, verbose=0)

print(predicted)
print(my_sequence)
```

Right now, I am choosing my training sample by hand but I want to train my entire dataset much like bootstrapping where I train 1-50, predict the next 50; train 2-50, predict the next 50… until the end of the test set then compare my prediction against the actual values.

Would this be done via batching the data or k-fold validation? Also, how would one go about it or calculate the appropriate evaluation metric?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should strengthen your foundation in machine learning first. Also, I would advise you to look for a higher quality paper (can't get much lower than this) that has a public repository. If you want the model to predict a set of value, you obviously want that to be penalized in the loss function, which means you need to appropriately structure your data.

Comment: Okay, yes I'm totally new to ML. I found out that its called the sliding window method and am trying to implement it with the predictions on each slide.